# Wikipedia Image list show from wikipedia xml api

Tags: c#, xml, image, wikipedia-api

I am trying to write a code in which I got as xml format for the first image api from wikipedia. Now I want to parse it through c#. But I cannot get the image while running code. here is my code.

```
namespace WikiAPIWinForm
{
     public partial class WikiForm : Form
   {

    private const string url1_Image1 = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Schloss%20Neuschwanstein%202013.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=comment|url|dimensions&format=xml&iiurlwidth=300"; //show 1st image
    private const string url1_Image2 = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Neuschwanstein%20castle.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=comment|url|dimensions&format=xml&iiurlwidth=300";// show another image
    private const string url1_Image3 = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Hohenschwangau_-_Schloss_Neuschwanstein5.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=comment|url|dimensions&format=xml&iiurlwidth=300";// show another image

   public WikiForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


        XDocument xmlDocument1 = XDocument.Load(url1_Image1);
        XDocument xmlDocument2 = XDocument.Load(url1_Image2);
        XDocument xmlDocument3 = XDocument.Load(url1_Image3);


        var image1 = (from page in xmlDocument1.Descendants("page")
                      select new AllImage
                      {
                          Title1 = page.Attribute("title").Value,
                          Imagerepository1 = page.Attribute("imagerepository").Value,
                          Url1 = page.Element("imageinfo").Element("ii").Attribute("thumburl").Value
                      });

        ShowImages1(image1);

        var image2 = (from page in xmlDocument2.Descendants("page")
                      select new AllImage
                      {
                          Title2 = page.Attribute("title").Value,
                          Imagerepository2 = page.Attribute("imagerepository").Value,
                          Url2 = page.Element("imageinfo").Element("ii").Attribute("thumburl").Value
                      });

        ShowImages2(image2);

        var image3 = (from page in xmlDocument3.Descendants("page")
                      select new AllImage
                      {
                          Title3 = page.Attribute("title").Value,
                          Imagerepository2 = page.Attribute("imagerepository").Value,
                          Url3 = page.Element("imageinfo").Element("ii").Attribute("thumburl").Value
                      });

        ShowImages3(image3);
    }






     private void ShowImages1(IEnumerable<AllImage> image1)
    {
        var image = image1.First();

        pictureLabel1.Text = image.Title1;
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox1.LoadAsync(image.Url1);// asynchronous loading

    }



    private void ShowImages2(IEnumerable<AllImage> image2)
    {
        var image = image2.First();

        pictureLabel2.Text = image.Title2;
        pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox2.LoadAsync(image.Url2);// asynchronous loading
    }

    private void ShowImages3(IEnumerable<AllImage> image3)
    {
        var image = image3.First();

        pictureLabel3.Text = image.Title3;
        pictureBox3.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox3.LoadAsync(image.Url3);// asynchronous loading

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false; // to prevent a new download until you have finished the old one

    XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(url1_Image);

    var images = (from page in xmlDocument.Descendants("page")
                  select new AllImage
                  {
                      Title = page.Attribute("title").Value,
                      Imagerepository = page.Attribute("imagerepository").Value,
                      Url = page.Element("imageinfo").Element("ii").Attribute("url").Value
                  });

    ShowImages(images);
};

private void ShowImages(IEnumerable<AllImage> images)
{
    var image = images.First();

    label1.Text = image.Title;
    pictureBox1.LoadAsync(image.Url); // asynchronous loading
}
```

After downloading the image you need to make the button available.

```
void pictureBox1_LoadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

We strongly recommend to give normal names to the controls. For example, `buttonLoad`, `labelTitle`, `pictureBoxWikiImage`.

In addition, I see in XML information about only one image. So, for what the IEnumerable collection?

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I wanted to do. But I have a question regarding downloading the pic. if I do not want to download then What shoud I do. Can I show Image directly from url?

Comment: my plan was to create it for 1 image at first. If I succeed then I implement all images here. so that I made IEnumerable collection

Comment: @nowshinreza - In any case, the image first must be downloaded. Web browsers first load it, then shows. If you do not use asynchronous, then your form will freeze until the image is loaded. On a slow connection (like me) it is well noticeable.

Comment: Hi could you please fix this code. I am trying to run a for each loop for String list. But everytime shows lots of error.

Comment: @nowshinreza - Show us your string list. [Edit] your question or ask new one.

Comment: Hi, I edit my code. Now I added two more picture. But I think the way I wrote the code is not so good for use. I want to make list of urls. and then pass this list through xmlDocument.load(url). But I failed in that process several times.